# How to update many states in one useEffect react?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm working on form validation. When some of my fields are empty, I'd like to display the errors. My idea is to hide error, when field is not empty.

Althought, it works fine in my folowing code, I'd like to write it in other way.
I mean to get rid of multiple useEffects here. I think about one useEffect, but don't know how implement it.

```
const MyComponent = ({}) => {
    
  const [ name, setName ] = useState('')
  const [ friends, setFriends ] = useState([])
  const [ socials, setSocials ] = useState([])
  const [ errors, setErrors ] = useState([])
    
  useEffect(() => {
    if (name && errors.includes('nameNotProvided')) {
        onHideError('nameNotProvided')
    }
  }, [ name ])
    
  useEffect(() => {
    if (friends && errors.includes('friendsNotSelected')) {
       onHideError('friendsNotSelected')
    }
  }, [ friends ])
    
  useEffect(() => {
    if (socials && errors.includes('socialsNotSelected')) {
        onHideError('socialsNotSelected')
    }
  }, [ socials ])
    
     return (...)
}
```

I tried to do that like this, but it gives me wrong result.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (name && errors.includes('nameNotProvided')) {
        onHideError('nameNotProvided')
    }
    if (friends && errors.includes('friendsNotSelected')) {
       onHideError('friendsNotSelected')
    }
    if (socials && errors.includes('socialsNotSelected')) {
        onHideError('socialsNotSelected')
    }   
}, [ name, friends, socials ])
```

Do you know how to handle it?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to give a default state to your `useState` hook:

```
    const [myFooBar, setFoo] = useState(
        {
            'foo': false, 
            'bar': false
        }
    );
```

Changing the values:

```
setFoo(
  prevState => ({
    ...prevState,
    'foo': true
  })
);
```

```
setFoo(
  prevState => ({
    ...prevState,
    'bar': true
  })
);
```

Access it like this:

```
myFooBar.foo
myFooBar.bar
```

Or check out: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer